# Select data using integer on subquery - Sql command

Tags: c#, sql, database, t-sql

I'm trying to select data from a db hosted in a server using classic SqlConnection and SqlCommand class.

---

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
                    ("SELECT data" +
                    "FROM table" +
                    "WHERE id_of_data" +
                    "IN(51729,52434,51545,52612)"
                    , sqlConnection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConnection.Close();
```

The connection is ok, but when i execute the command using

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The compiler throws me an exception : "Incorrect syntax near IN(51729)".

Somebody know what happens ?

Comment: Leave each query line a space bro, then check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just doing a bad string concat.  Try this and note the added spaces:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
    ("SELECT data " +
    "FROM table " +
    "WHERE id_of_data " +
    "IN(51729,52434,51545,52612)"
    , sqlConnection);
```

Your old query actually was:

> SELECT dataFROM tableWHERE id_of_dataIN(51729,52434,51545,52612)